# Submit selection on Bootstrap typeahead() autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

How do I autosubmit the selection made with Twitter Bootstrap typeahead()??

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: If you're still looking, I created an extension to the Typeahead plugin to add some functionality like the one you've asked about. https://github.com/tcrosen/Bootstrap-Typeahead-Extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there are a few git merge requests. This one does the job and allows you to send an array of objects to typeahead: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/1751

Comment: ya I understand it's not the best possible solution. But it was the only thing I could think of as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 22):

There is a clean way using the `updater` callback:

```
input.typeahead({
    'source' : ['foo', 'bar'],
    'updater' : function(item) {
        this.$element[0].value = item;
        this.$element[0].form.submit();
        return item;
    }
});
```

When user selects an option (either by mouse click or keyboard), the callback populates the input box and sends the form.

Comment: field is selected (and populated) but form is not submitted. `$('#search-box.typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(states),
      updater : function(item) {
        this.$element[0].value = item;
        this.$element[0].form.submit();
        return item;
      }
    });`

Answer (score 11):

If you use the external [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) plugin (recommended for Bootstrap 3):

To trigger a form on select just use the custom events.

```
$('#my-input')
   .typeahead({/* put you options here */})
   .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
     e.target.form.submit();
   });
```

More info on custom events [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#custom-events) and demo about [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/CNMfL/2/).

Comment: saved my life @HaNdTriX

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Might not be the best solution, but I just tried this on my typeahead setup locally and it worked.

If your typeahead looks something like this...

```
    <form id="test-form" method="post" action="">
            <input id="test-input" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" 
             data-source='["1","2',"3"]' />
    </form>
```

Then you can submit it with this javascript.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#test-input').change(function() {
          $('#test-form').submit();
       });
   </script>
```

Comment: Hmm just tried it out. Only seems to work when I directly select the option, but not when I hit enter or tab to select.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `blur` callback on the input. Be aware that you need to wait for a short period, that typeahead can change the value in the input and the `blur` callback is not called before that. It's just a workaround, but it works.

```
$('input.myTypeaheadInput').blur(function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.console && console.log('Works with clicking on li item and navigating with the keyboard. Yay!');
    }, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To populate a value of a hidden field in an html form from the typeahead data selection, I did the following:

```
$('#prefetch').typeahead({
 hint: true,
 highlight: true,
 minLength: 1
},
{
 name: 'trees',
 source: trees,
 limit: 15 
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(e) {
 var result = $('#prefetch').val()
 $('#formpane input[name=\"myID\"]').val(result)
});
```

For reference, here's the html code:

```
<body>
 <div id="formpane">
  <form action="/thanks" method="POST">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="select categories" id="prefetch">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="myID" />
  </form>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_file_above.js"></script>
</body>
```