# Trigger Bootstrap typeahead on paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, paste, typeahead

I've been trying to manually trigger the typeahead search on right-click paste by catching the paste event as follows but I can't seem to find a way to trigger the typeahead's 'matcher' function manually to query the entered string.

```
$('#search-bar').bind("paste", function(e)
{
    $(this).trigger("keydown"); // Tried keyup, input to no avail!
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by 'trigger the typehead'? Submit the search? Do you have a search button. Paste the html code of the whole form

Comment: I just need to be able to run the typeahead search that is run internally in the typeahead.js by the keyup function. I can't find a way to run it without keyup'ing and calling a `.trigger('keyup')` doesn't work.

Comment: Why is it not already behaving in this way? I just tried [this example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and I pasted a single letter and a few countries showed up. Also, why can't you use $('#search-bar').bind('change',...) It's a text field so it should work the same as paste

Comment: Sorry, just read the whole post. Yeah basically submit the search. I don't have a search button, its solely typeahead, to select an item you just click it in the list or hit enter and I handle that accordingly. Its not as such a form, its just an input that is selected in jQuery and typeahead is then called on it as follows.

`<input id = "search-bar" autocomplete = "off" class = "form-control" type = "text" placeholder = "Search...">`

Comment: Was testing the same solution with `keyup` and [`bootstrap-3-typeahead`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-3-typeahead) and noticed that only the *first* paste event didn't trigger the typeahead functionality, but subsequent ones worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15179532/559079

```
        $('#search-bar').typeahead({
            'updater' : function(item) {
              myAjaxFunction(item);
            }
        });

function myAjaxFunction (item){
$.ajax({ //DO STUFF HERE });
}
```

Comment: I've already written the updater function..

The typeahead isn't the problem, it searches perfectly. I just can't get it to search without physically typing into the bar.

Out of interest, I tried adding this but it didn't work. My search doesn't use a form it uses ajax on select of a returned item.

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. If you have updater that works and fires like it's supposed to then simply move all your ajax stuff into a function and fire it trough the updated. You really don't need keydown events and triggers (Updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search-bar').bind("paste", function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){self.trigger("keydown");}, 0);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

(1) my lazy solution: call `$('#yourtypeaheadfield').trigger('keyup')` to "impersonate" a keyup / keypress event .. this is how Typeahead hooks into the JQuery API.

(2) "better" answer: fire the typeahead event exlicitly - `$().trigger('typeahead.updater')` - I could not figure out the syntax, though, and it is not documented (at least not for bootstrap 2.3.2).